# PolymerElements, paper-icon-button to be specific, not showing up as expected

Tags: polymer

I just started with Polymer and I'm using paper-icon-button to test this out. I think I set things up correctly because the button I used have ripple effect; when I set the `src` property, my intended picture showed up.

```
<!-- This works -->
<paper-icon-button src="http://placekitten.org/g/50/50"></paper-icon-button>
```

However, I failed to use default icon, for example:

```
<!-- This does not work. There is a blank icon. 
                      However, ripple effect still works on click -->
<paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
```

I ran the polymer project on a Linux server. The demo doesn't work on my computer either. Here is what the demo should look like: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-icon-button?view=demo:demo/index.html
Here is the demo running on my `polyserve`: [image]

I setup `paper-icon-button` using bower command instead of zip file so I would assume that all the dependencies are there. Not sure what is missing :s please help me out thanks!

Comment: did u install dependencies locally?  npm install -g gulp bower && npm install && bower install

Comment: @Robert Rowntree I did them all

Comment: changes in the last week AFAIK .. recheck the git docs... https://github.com/polymerelements/paper-icon-button

Answer (score 0):

You also need to import iron-icons. Look at this [demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/blob/master/demo/index.html) 
and this [example repository](https://github.com/rofrol/polymer-trying).

Proper way to initialize project on Windows:

1. [Install yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install)
2. open `git bash`
3. `mkdir -p /c/projects/polymer && cd /c/projects/polymer`
4. `yarn add --dev bower`
5. `./node_modules/.bin/bower init`
6. If you see: "bower ENOINT Register requires an interactive shell" run above command in `cmd.exe`. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683378/bower-init-command-error-gitbash-in-windows).
7. `./node_modules/.bin/bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-icons`
8. `./node_modules/.bin/bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-icon-button`
9. Create index.html with content at the end of this post
10. `yarn add --dev http-server`
11. `./node_modules/http-server`
12. Open `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in web browser

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <paper-icon-button icon="favorite" title="heart"></paper-icon-button>
  </body>
</html>
```