# bower init command error (gitbash) in windows

Tags: git, github, bower, git-bash, bower-install

When i run bower init in gitbash ,following error is displayed:

> bower ENOINT        Register requires an interactive shell
>
> Additional error details: Note that you can manually force an
>   interactive shell with --config.interactive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue: `mintty.exe`

[Issue 802](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/802) does provide a good explanation:

> I've tracked this down to an issue with [`mintty.exe`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mintty/).
>
> In the `bower/lib/config.js` file (line 34 for bower v 1.4.1), `tty.isatty(1)` returns false under `mintty.exe`, but true if you run `cygwin.bat` (which is `bash --login -i` using the Windows terminal).
>
> Here's a convenient way to check your terminal:

```
node -e "var tty=require('tty'); console.log('tty.isatty(1):' + tty.isatty(1))"
```

Possibly related: [mintty - issue #56 "Improve support for native console programs"](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56).

> For those stumbling across this issue looking for a solution, the obvious quick workaround for this issue is to simply avoid using mintty.
>   This doesn't mean you have to return to using the Windows terminal for bash, as there are other alternatives:
>
> - See [Terminal Setup in Windows 7](http://blog.jaykanakiya.com/terminal-setup-in-windows-7/) and/or [Replacing default git bash console with Console2](http://buildstarted.com/2012/05/11/replacing-default-git-bash-console-with-console2/) for instructions for configuring Console2 with bash.
> - Turn off the menus, tool bars, and status bars,
> - create a shortcut named "`Cygwin`" or "`Bash`", change the shortcut's icon to `C:\cygwin64\Cygwin-Terminal.ico` and you'll probably never know the difference.
>
> P.S. If you've ever noted other issues with `mintty.exe`, like msysgit not prompting for a password properly or the node repl not working, this is probably the same issue.

---

### Workarounds:

> - do this from the run command

```
    cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
```

> then `bower init` will work and you can do everything in minw64, mintty, or git-bash whatever it is called.

OR

> If you are using windows run bower init using CMD

OR

> if you are using git bash follow these steps:
>
> - Uninstall existing GIT bash
> - Reinstall GIT bash
> - Set up during installation:
>
>   - 3a: Select> Use Git form the Windows Command Prompt
>   - 3b: Select> Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings
>   - 3c: Select> Use Windows' default console window

Comment: thanks,your 1st method worked but do I have to run this everytime whenever I need bower?

Comment: @KiranSaxena yes, to open a compatible shell (ie one which does not use mintty)

Answer (score 1):

Run the command through another terminal, like the `Node.js` command prompt, the Windows `cmd` itself or another command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

well you don't really have to uninstall/reinstall, you can just use the Win CMD.
do you bower init then switch back to MinW64.
edit found a fix...start git-bash like this
use run command, you can change the shortcut later

```
cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
```